# Python scripts communicate

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to write a game manager/controller for games like Tic-Tac-Toe or checkers/chess that works like this:

Game Arbiter: Controls the gameplay of a game and relays opponent moves to each player. Also determines if a move is a legal one

GamePlayer.py

- Will play a move when asked by the Arbiter

GameArbiter.py

- Will decide which player goes first
- Will decide if move is legal
- Will keep a reference to the two players
- Will ask the correct player for a move and provide current gamestate

The problem I have is how will the Arbiter communicate with the Players? I wanted to use PIPE.communicate() but it seems that only works if the Player terminates after every .communicate() request. My code is as such:

GameArbiter.py:

```
import subprocess
import sys

player1 = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "GamePlayer.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

instruction = "GetMove"
out, _ = player1.communicate(instruction.encode())
print(out.decode())     # process input from player

# do some stuff

instruction = "GetMove"
out, _ = player1.communicate(instruction.encode())
print(out.decode())     # process input from player
```

GamePlayer.py:

```
instruction = input()
if(instruction == "GetMove"):
    print("Bc4xc5")
else:
    print("InvalidInstruction")
```

Of course after the second .communicate() python crashes since player1 is no longer an open file

My question is how would I write (in python) a delegate who could actively talk back and forth with multiple children asynchronously?

Answer (score 1):

`communicate` is a high-level function which sits atop of `player1.stdin.write` and `player1.stdout.read`. There is a way to implement what you are trying to do but this will introduce a lot of complexity into your code (you will need to spawn separate threads to read from stdout of another process, flushing, etc). If you want to go through all that you can check the source code of `communicate` function.

More standard solution would be to use client-server architecture to communicate over the network

Answer (score 1):

If all this is happening on one machine, then I would wonder if you need to have separate processes.

If the goal is to move the player processes to separate machines, then I would suggest you use network communication between the processes in a typical client-server model. In which case I would recommend [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

> What is Twisted?
>
> Twisted is an event-driven networking engine written in Python and licensed under the open source  MIT license.

Comment: If I wanted to do this on a single computer but emulate it as a network is this possible? For instance write it to work on a network but run it on one computer instead?

Comment: Yes, all network communication (TCP sockets etc) can occur locally by connecting to the loopback address (127.0.0.1 for ipv4) instead of a remote server address

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make GamePlayer a function that get's called infinitely?

Or better yet, a Class for which each player in a game that would inherit from it.

Comment: Abstracting code to complete my goals is one thing, but I don't know how to get it to work in theory. That comes first